# Database + hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

How to write complex queries in hibernate? I mean sql queries like inner join or so. If i want to access datas from two tables what do i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding how to configure hibernate in order to access MySql, [check this example](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/firstexample.shtml)

I dint understand the part where you said "**using web services**".

You want to do some operations using hibernate, via web services ? If yes, write a method which does the operations on hibernate and simply expose that method.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help. I was searching exactly this. Hope i can expose as many methods as i want using a single wsdl. Ant these methods can use hibernate to access database. Thanks again

Comment: You can expose as many methods as you want. If the problem is solved, accept the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your complex query can call this method

```
 public <T> List<T> getCustomRecordsForSQL(String sqlQueryStr, T instance) {
   Session sess = initSession();
   HIFILogger.logInfo(sqlQueryStr);
   List<T> retval = null;
   try {
      Query query = sess.createSQLQuery(sqlQueryStr)
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(instance.getClass()));
      sess.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);
      retval = query.list();
      if (retval != null) {
         HIFILogger.logInfo("Record Returned - " + retval.size());
      }
   } catch (HibernateException e) {
      HIFILogger.logInfo(e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace(); //FIXME
      throw e;
   } finally {
      if (sess != null) {
         sess.close();
      }
   }
   return retval;
}
```

The caller method should send the query itself and the class e.g

```
@Override
public List<Employee> getRecordsForClassName(Integer userID) throws UserGoalException {
    String query = "SELECT Employee.*, Employee.Name, Org.Description FROM Employee,OrgWHERE Employee.GoalID = Org.UserID AND Employee.userID = "
            + userID;
    List<Employee> empGoalList= getCustomRecordsForSQL(query, new Employee());
    return empGoalList;
}
```

Please ignore the lack of usage of parameters or null checks. It's just for example.